# React TypeScript: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, canvas

I seem to be able to create the canvas but when I come to get the context

```
  const resizeImage = async (maxSize: number) => {
    const image = originalImage;
    const id = positionId;
    const resizeCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    resizeCanvas.width = maxSize;
    resizeCanvas.height = maxSize;
    const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = resizeCanvas.getContext('2D');
//         ^ Error
    ...
```

The error is

```
Type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D | ImageBitmapRenderingContext | WebGLRenderingContext | WebGL2RenderingContext | null' is not assignable to type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: It means that `resizeCanvas.getContext('2D')` can return null, but you are assigning it to a variable of type `CanvasRenderingContext2D` (i.e. cannot be null). So you need to make sure the result is not null before assigning it. What do you want to do if it's null, throw an error?

Comment: I think your suggestion helped I used `const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = resizeCanvas.getContext('2d')!;` <== notice the exclamation on the end and lowercase d in`2d`

Comment: Mmm yes you could do that, but the non-null assertion operator should only really be used if you're absolutely sure that `resizeCanvas.getContext('2D')` will never return null during runtime. If you are sure then ok, but if not better to check for null first, then handle it before assigning to `ctx`. Otherwise your program may crash during runtime.

Comment: would you care to submit an answer with an example and ill accept it

Answer (score 6):

The error means that `resizeCanvas.getContext('2D')` can return null, but you are assigning it to a variable of type `CanvasRenderingContext2D` (i.e. this cannot be null). So you need to make sure the result is not null before assigning it. Also I guess you want to make sure it's of type `CanvasRenderingContext2D` rather than `ImageBitmapRenderingContext` etc. You could do:

```js
 const resizeImage = async (maxSize: number) => {
    const image = originalImage;
    const id = positionId;
    const resizeCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    resizeCanvas.width = maxSize;
    resizeCanvas.height = maxSize;
    const res = resizeCanvas.getContext('2D');
    if (!res || !(res instanceof CanvasRenderingContext2D)) {
        throw new Error('Failed to get 2D context');
    }
    const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = res;
```

Comment: Ive just tried you answer and I get `Type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D | ImageBitmapRenderingContext | WebGLRenderingContext | WebGL2RenderingContext | null' is not assignable to type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.ts(2322)`

Comment: Oh right, TS must not treat an instanceof condition as excluding null. I've edited the answer, does it work now?

Comment: Oh right, well I'm not sure then, I'd have thought that should work.

Comment: this is a strange one but im not getting `Argument of type '"Failed to get 2D context"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PropsWithChildren<PropsInterface>'.
  Type '"Failed to get 2D context"' is not assignable to type 'PropsInterface'.ts(2345)` this is indicated with on the throw new Error line

Comment: If you look for a more "to the point answer" - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71230658/1461862

Comment: the `'2D'` in `const res = resizeCanvas.getContext('2D');` causes an error. I think it was a typo because changing it to the lower case `'2d'` makes it work

Answer (score 1):

Just declare yout variable like this type: `CanvasRenderingContext2D | null;`

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild('soccerField', { static: true }) soccerCanvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement> ;
  private ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D | null;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let element = this.soccerCanvas.nativeElement ;
    this.ctx = element.getContext('2d');
  }
```

Comment: This answer did it for me, using Angular 13

Answer (score 0):

The following will work

```
const resizeImage = async (maxSize: number) => {
const image = originalImage;
const id = positionId;
const resizeCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
resizeCanvas.width = maxSize;
resizeCanvas.height = maxSize;
const ctx = resizeCanvas.getContext('2D') as unknown as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### TYPO:

It is `getContext("2d")` not `"2D"`, case matters.

When passed an invalid argument this method will return `null`.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const upperCased = canvas.getContext('2D');
const lowerCased = canvas.getContext('2d');

console.log( 'upper-cased', upperCased ) // null
console.log( 'lower-cased', lowerCased ) // { "drawImage":...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring the property and assigning it after, just make it local and then export it. When you declare outside you need to nullify it first and canvas does not accept it.

So change this:

```js
/** Canvas 2d context */
  private context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.context = (this.canvas.nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement).getContext('2d');
 ...
 }
```

to this:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      var canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
      var cx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
      this.method(cx); <== Pass it as Parameter
    }, 1);
  }
```

It will not give the error about canvas being null. Hope it may help.
Obs.: This is running for ANGULAR Applications.

Answer (score 0):

#### What a context does?

The context generated by the `getContext` method is an object used to *produce images* from a *canvas*.

The context can generate 2d images or 3d images or bitmap only images.
It depends on the setting you pass to the method.

```
getContext('2d')             -> object to generate 2d images
getContext('webgl')          -> object to generate 3d images
getContext('bitmaprenderer') -> object to generate bitmap images
```

See [HTMLCanvasElement: getContext() method Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext#parameters) for a full list.

#### What does a null context means?

It means the browser doesn't support that type of rendering.
The browser can't produce the image.

#### What you can do to deal with it?

Accept `Context` and `null`

```
// 'CanvasRenderingContext2D | ImageBitmapRenderingContext | WebGLRenderingContext | WebGL2RenderingContext | null'
const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D | null = resizeCanvas.getContext('2d');

// if you use another context then change accordingly
// let say WebGLRenderingContext then
const ctx: WebGLRenderingContext | null = resizeCanvas.getContext('webgl');
```

When you generate the image check for `null` and throw an error in case

```
getImg() : Uint8ClampedArray {
    // The browser is not able to generateimages
    if (ctx == null) {
        throw Error("2d context not supported");
    }

    ctx.drawImage(src, 0, 0, width, height);
    return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;
}
```

#### Why do i need to throw the error?

Because anyway when the context is `null` *you'll have a runtime error* as there is no `drawImage` in `ctx` as it is `null`.

So, better you *rise your own error* and *deal with it* when the browser doesn't support the feature.